# Spacetree canvas not completely cleared with Android default browser

Tags: thejit

I included a JIT spacetree in a project, it works very well with any browser except Android default browser: some nodes are not correctly cleared during animations.

We can see it with the [Spacetree demo](http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.html): navigate in this tree with for example Android browser 4.0+, or [this Android emulator](https://www.manymo.com/) and as you will see a few nodes in background are not cleared.

I tried to disable animations (using method ST.select instead of ST.onCLick), it is the same. I also tried to fill the whole Canvas with a black rectangle in "onBeforeCompute" event, but those background nodes are redrawn each time.

Please any clue about this issue will be much appreciated